# What is meant by invalid page table entry?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, tlb

From wikipedia:

> The page table lookup may fail for two reasons. The first is if there is no translation available for the virtual address, meaning that virtual address is invalid.

Furthermore, if each process has its own page table, this means that the entries in the page table will all have some translation from virtual address to physical address. What is then meant by a page table entry being invalid? If the entry exists, it means that the translation exists, because an entry is nothing but a mapping from a virtual address to physical address.

Comment: Your quote from the chapter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Translation_failures is cut in the middle. The article talks about virtual address being invalid. Not about page table entry being invalid. Furthermore the fact that process has its own page table does not mean at all that the page table covers whole (possible very very large) virtual memory. Also http://wiki.osdev.org/Page_table#Page_Faults says "_..A page fault exception is caused when a process is seeking to access an area of virtual memory that is not mapped to any physical memory.._"

Comment: PTE formats typically have a valid bit indicating that the translation is valid (other mechanisms could be used such as denying all permissions; a single valid bit is simpler and allows the OS to use the rest of the PTE for storing information). The existence of a PTE does not mean that the translation is valid.

Comment: There is potential to this question but I don't know if it's phrased correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the Wikipedia entry does not handle all cases. For a given virtual address the first step in the translation is to find the corresponding page table entry.

Problem 1: The page table entry may not exist at all. AN operating system may limit the page table size so that it does not cover the full virtual address range and the specified address is outside that range. This can also occur with multi-level page tables where not all the levels have been filled in.

Problem 2: The page table entry exists but the page had not been mapped to the virtual address space.

{these first two are most likely to be classified as invalid pages table entries)

Problem 3: The page is not in physical memory [Page fault].

Problem 4: The type of access requested is not permitted in the current processor mode.
E.g., User mode write to a page that only permits user mode reads;
Kernel mode execute to a page that only permits read and write.

Comment: if a page has a page table entry, doesn't that give it a virtual address? (problem 2)

Comment: The question is what does it mean to have a page table entry? Is there just an available slot for the page table entry or is the table filled in? If the former, you could have a page table entry for a logical page but with no corresponding virtual page.

Comment: How does it actually happen

Comment: Let's a assume the OS has a linear page table. Let's say that the system parameters/process quotas have the OS initially create a page table with 10,000 entries. So now you have 10,000 entries but nothing mapped to them. As the process requests pages from the OS, the OS will fill in those entries.

Comment: I agree with you, but is our assumption a reality of how they are implemented

Comment: it's system dependent.